# How can I use inline style with data attribute using JavaScript no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can use in my html file like this

```
<div data-width="250px"></div>
<div data-width="calc(100% - 300px);"></div>
```

I need to output like this

```
<div data-width="250px" style="width:250px"></div>
<div data-width="calc(100% - 300px);" style="width:calc(100% - 300px);"></div>
```

Comment: so you want to grab whatever is inside the data-width and apply that into inline styling using plain javascript?, and isn't it easier to just add it inline from the start or is that not an option?

Comment: Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the grey check mark in my answer. You can accept my answer this way if i have really helped you.

Answer (score 2):

you may use like following

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute("data-width","250px");
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].setAttribute("style","width:250px");
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].setAttribute("data-width","calc(100% - 300px)");
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].setAttribute("style","width:calc(100% - 300px);");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) along with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to apply the `style` width property to your `divs` which are stored in the `data-width` attribute.

To get the `data-width` from each element we can use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute#:%7E:text=The%20getAttribute()%20method%20of,Non%2Dexisting%20attributes%20for%20details.) method.

**Edit:** You can select multiple elements like `section`, `h1`, `span` in the same `querySelectorAll`

**Live Demo:** Using only JavaScript

```js
let getDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div, h1, section')

getDivs.forEach(function(div) {
  let data = div.getAttribute('data-width')
  div.style.width = data
})
```

```html
<div data-width="250px">1</div>
<div data-width="calc(100% - 300px)">2</div>
<h1 data-width="210px">3</h1>
<section data-width="150px">4</section>
```

Comment: Yes Great thanks a lot for your answer. But one think if I can use it for any type of elements like (span, section, div, h1, article etc) that's mean I can use it any time any place any elements don't //Apply to all divs need to apply any elements when I need  But how??

Comment: @AbdulKhalik yes that’s correct you can add span h1 and all others you want that data-width from in querySelectorAll('div, span') this way with a commas seperation.